# Add doubleclick handler on table cell after response

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, eventhandler

I would like to add a doubleclick event handler to table cell AFTER the table was "downloaded" from a servlet and "inserted" by javascript. 
I have a javascript cycle that iterate on a xml response to map datas ini table. Said that a cell can be

```
<td class='red' ></td>
```

I want to add a function on that cell, I've tried several solution, but none works.One is:

```
$(".red").on("dblclick",myfunction);
```

Help?

Update:
Table constructor ofter response received

```
function handleResponse(responseXML) {
    var i;
    var x=responseXML.getElementsByTagName("row");
    var out="<table><tr><th >Description</th><th >State</th><th>Note</th></tr>";
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        out+="<tr>";
    var Description = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var State = x[i].getElementsByTagName("State")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var note =  x[i].getElementsByTagName("Note")[0].childNodes[0];
    var note_text=" ";
    if (!(typeof note === "undefined") && !(note=='null')) {
        note_text=note.nodeValue;
    }
    out += "<td>"+Description+ "</td>";
    if(State==0)
        out+="<td class='white' ></td>";
    else if(State==1)
        out+="<td class='red' ></td>";
    else if(State==2)
        out+="<td class='yellow' ></td>";
    else if(State==3)
        out+="<td class='green' ></td>";

    out+="<td>" + note_text + "</td></tr>";
    }
    var output = document.getElementById("mytable");
    out+="</table>";
    $().on("click",".red",update());  //here is the point
    output.innerHTML=out;
}
```

Comment: `$(".red ,.rosso").on("click",myfunction)` if you need like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Based on your comments you can try this:

When you print the `td` change the template a little:

```
out+="<td class='red' ondblclick='openModal()'></td>";
```

And then in your js file add something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function openModal() {
      alert( "Double clicked." );
      // Or call your other function here...
    };
});
```

You can do it with several ways also, check here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp

Comment: No, I apoogize, I was not clear. The scenario is this:
1)Load html page with a combobox
2)select a choise and execute a request to servlet
3)receive xml data and create a table to show in div

On poit 3, I want to add an event listener that on double click on a cell, it show a modal div.

Hope i've been more clear

Comment: So the `.rosso` is the element you want to double click?

Comment: rosso is red (in italian). Sorry for my very bad formed code, I've done copy/paste errors. So, I want that on double click on a cell which class is "red", a modal div is shown

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle then and I'll do my best for you.

Comment: the only code that do somthing is: '
 $().on("click",".red",myfunction());
'
but it calls myfuntion only on table construnction cycle

Comment: So `$().on("dblclick",".red",myfunction());` Doesn't work?

Comment: Works, but not as I want. myfunction is called(executed) at the end of "handleResponse", and not on doubleclick on cell which class is "red"

Comment: Yes because you are calling it there. Check my updated answer. You jus't to have it outside of your function to make it work outside of the handleResponse function.

Comment: It not works, and I think It's right because table and its cell "red" is "created" and modified after document is ready, so when document is ready table and cell do not exist.

Comment: Updated again with `ondblclick`

Comment: Great mate. That's the very first solution I've tried, dunno why but my first attempt did not work, your last update works (without the "And then in your js file add something like this......" part)

Comment: Upvoted, but the vote is stored and not shown publicly